# Копирование на новый лист в первую пустую строку Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, макросы, макрос

Есть код, который, если заполнен столбец А, то копирует определенные столбцы на лист B. Можно ли сделать так, чтобы копирование происходило на первую пустую строку?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    Dim a(), i&, ii&
    a = Sheets(1).UsedRange.Value
    ReDim b(1 To UBound(a, 1), 1 To UBound(a, 1))
    For i = 1 To UBound(a)
        If (a(i, 1)) = 1 Then
            ii = ii + 1
                b(ii, 1) = a(i, 1) 'A
                b(ii, 2) = a(i, 2) 'B
                b(ii, 3) = a(i, 3) 'C
        End If
    Next
Range("A:C") = b
End Sub
```

Comment: *Можно ли сделать так, чтобы копирование происходило на первую пустую строку?* Можно, делайте, разрешения спрашивать необязательно. Для поиска такой строки используйте UsedRange, например...

Comment: >>  *Worksheet_Activate... если заполнен столбец А, то копирует...* - зашли на лист, данные всех строк с заполненными ячейками в первом столбце копируются на другой лист. 5 раз вышли-зашли - 5 раз повторилось копирование :)